# SVG file does not show in <img> element on Firefox, but it does show in Chrome, Edge, and Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, svg

I changed the name of the .svg file for this example, but basically I have some graphs that output as .svg files and they can be seen in Chrome, Edge, and Internet Explorer, but for some reason the only way I can get .svg files to show in Firefox is if I open the .svg file in a text editor and copy the code and paste it in my html document. What am I doing wrong?

```
    <img
    src="graph.svg"
    alt="graph"
    height="500"
    width="500" >
```

Comment: svg is supported by [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img) check if you got any error logged in the console.

Comment: What about the doctype declaration? Did you have one? I remember that some SVG without an XML namespace wasn’t displayed on some browsers. Maybe, you’d just have to add this to solve the issue. Check also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/SVG_In_HTML_Introduction#Related_Links

Comment: Can you try this  `<img
    src="graph.svg"
    alt="graph"
    height="auto"
    width="500px" >`

Comment: @FedericoMoretti Can you explain more? I just have `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: @Manjuboyz I tried that and it didn't work.

Comment: @Ma'mounothman No errors in the console

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve] so we can see for ourselves what is happening.  Are you testing using a proper webserver, or just via `file://`?

Comment: @PaulLeBeau I was testing this locally. It works now. Thanks!

Comment: @ScottF I meant the SVG, not the HTML: sometimes, if it lacks the XML namespace, it can’t be shown on some browsers. Glad you solved!